# How do I prove that $2\cos (2\theta + {\pi \over 3}) \equiv - 2\sin(2\theta - {\pi \over 6})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Using the identity $\cos (\theta  + {\pi  \over 2}) \equiv  - \sin\theta $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the identity $\quad\cos\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{2}\right)\equiv−\sin\theta$,

Let $\;\color{green}{\bf x = 2\theta - \dfrac{\pi}{6}} \implies\left(\implies \color{blue}{\bf x + \dfrac{\pi}{2}}\; = \;\left(2\theta - \dfrac{\pi}{6}\right) + \dfrac{\pi}{2} \;= \;\color{blue}{\bf 2\theta + \dfrac{\pi}{3}}\right)$

$$2\cos \left(\color{blue}{\bf 2\theta + {\pi \over 3}}\right)\; = \;2\cos\left(\color{blue}{\bf x + \dfrac{\pi}{2}}\right) \;\equiv\; - 2\sin(\color{green}{\bf x})\; = \;-2\sin\left(\color{green}{\bf 2\theta - \dfrac{\pi}{6}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

In $\cos ( X + \frac {\pi}{2} ) = - \sin X$, set $X = 2 \theta - \frac { \pi} { 6} $.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\cos( \alpha+ \dfrac{\pi}{2})= - \sin \alpha$

Set $\alpha = (\theta - \dfrac{\pi}{6})$

$\cos (2\theta- \dfrac{\pi}{6}+ \dfrac{\pi}{2})=- \sin( 2\theta -\dfrac{\pi}{6})$